# Hawtio remote connect to a jolokia agent inside Karaf

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, hawtio

I have the following setup:

- Karaf 4.0.2 deployed inside docker on an EC2 instance.
- I have the jolokia feature installed in Karaf.
- Upon deployment the bundles start fine and the jolokia agent is listening on the 8181 port.

However, when I start Karaf locally and want to connect to this remote jolokia agent I get the error shown in the screenshot. The error pops up after the authentication popup windows comes.

I didn't see anything strange in the karaf logs either. Note, I can curl the url and get the json response back so I can verify the jolokia agent is answering. But something is not working when you do the same via hawtio. Note, I know it says port 80, we have url rewrite at our EC2 instance that then forwards the request to the correct ec2 instance and then to the karaf container. A curl to the same jolokia url works fine[image: HawtioError]

This is the curl response:

```
{"request":{"type":"version"},"value":{"agent":"1.3.0","protocol":"7.2","config":{"listenForHttpService":"true","agentId":"172.17.0.10-1-6bc13aa8-osgi","debug":"false","agentType":"servlet","policyLocation":"classpath:\/jolokia-access.xml","agentContext":"\/jolokia","serializeException":"false","mimeType":"text\/plain","authMode":"jaas","canonicalNaming":"true","historyMaxEntries":"10","realm":"karaf","includeStackTrace":"true","user":"karaf","useRestrictorService":"false","debugMaxEntries":"100"},"info":{"product":"felix","vendor":"Apache","version":"5.2.0"}},"timestamp":1479717185,"status":200}
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the workaround I found is that I have to specify the entire url in the "Host" input field in the connection settings. Putting the jolokia path in "Path" doesn't work.